# jQuery MovingBoxes add Opacity transition

Tags: jquery

It's all about this jQuery-Plugin:

https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/MovingBoxes

which basically scrolls content and also is able to resize non-active content. It's really nice and flexible after all, I want to add the functionality to fade non-active panels to a given opacity and fade the active panel to full opacity.

There are some approaches, namely found here:

https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/MovingBoxes/issues/69

but anyhow,

these are CSS3-Solutions and an image-overlay-solutions and those are both impracticable because of three reasons:

1.) The CSS3 just animates the fade-out of images correctly, but the current image is not faded in, because the current-class is applied after the animation is completed.

2.) Not all Browsers and of course not all mobile browsern support css3 transition

3.) The solution with an image-overlay is more a workaround and not very flexible.

So:

Is it not possible to somehow include jQuery.animate: Opacity while scrolling? Fading the current image to full opacity and fading the "other" images out?

Any help is welcome. I tried my luck with the JavaScript of moving boxes but it seems more complicated than I thought...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found it by myself. For fading to zero edit this part:

```
// Resize panels to normal
    base.returnToNormal = function(num, time){
        var panels = base.$panels.not(':eq(' + (num - base.adj) + ')').removeClass(o.currentPanel);
        if (o.reducedSize === 1) {
            panels.css({ width: base.regWidth }); // excluding fontsize change to prevent video flicker
        } else {
            panels.stop(true,false).animate({ width: base.regWidth, fontSize: o.reducedSize + 'em' , opacity: 0 }, (time === 0) ? 0 : o.speed);
        }
    };
```

and for fading to full opacity again edit this part:

```
// Zoom in on selected panel
        base.growBigger = function(num, time, flag){
            var panels = base.$panels.eq(num - base.adj);
            if (o.reducedSize === 1) {
                panels.css({ width: base.curWidth }); // excluding fontsize change to prevent video flicker
                // time delay prevents click outer panel from following links - fixes issue #67
                setTimeout(function(){
                    base.completed(num, flag);
                }, (time === 0) ? 0 : o.speed);
            } else {
                panels.stop(true,false).animate({ width: base.curWidth, fontSize: '1em', opacity: 1 }, (time === 0) ? 0 : o.speed, function(){
                    // completed event trigger
                    // even though animation is not queued, trigger is here because it is the last animation to complete
                    base.completed(num, flag);
                });
            }
        };
```

take care of the "animate" part there: It's the key.